# How Logical and Physical plan works when read Hive Partitioned ORC table in pyspark dataframe

Tags: dataframe, hive, pyspark, orc

I have created a spark dataframe reading csv from hdfs location.

```py
emp_df = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv") \
  .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED") \
  .option("header", "true") \
  .option("inferschema", "true") \
  .option("delimiter", ",").load(PATH_TO_FILE)
```

and saving this dataframe as Hive paritioned orc table using partitionBy method

```py
emp_df.repartition(5, 'emp_id').write.format('orc').partitionBy("emp_id").saveAsTable("UDB.temptable")
```

when I am reading this table as below method and If I look at the logical and physical plan, it seems that it has perfectly filtered the data using partition key column:

```py
emp_df_1 = spark.sql("select * from UDB.temptable where emp_id ='6'")
emp_df_1.explain(True)

***************************************************************************
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
'Project [*]
+- 'Filter ('emp_id = 6)
   +- 'UnresolvedRelation `UDB`.`temptable`

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
emp_name: string, emp_city: string, emp_salary: int, emp_id: int
Project [emp_name#7399, emp_city#7400, emp_salary#7401, emp_id#7402]
+- Filter (emp_id#7402 = cast(6 as int))
   +- SubqueryAlias temptable
      +- Relation[emp_name#7399,emp_city#7400,emp_salary#7401,emp_id#7402] orc

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Filter (isnotnull(emp_id#7402) && (emp_id#7402 = 6))
+- Relation[emp_name#7399,emp_city#7400,emp_salary#7401,emp_id#7402] orc

== Physical Plan ==
*(1) FileScan orc udb.temptable[emp_name#7399,emp_city#7400,emp_salary#7401,emp_id#7402] Batched: true, Format: ORC, Location: PrunedInMemoryFileIndex[hdfs://pathlocation/database/udb...., 
PartitionCount: 1, PartitionFilters: [isnotnull(emp_id#7402), (emp_id#7402 = 6)], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<emp_name:string,emp_city:string,emp_salary:int>
***************************************************************************
```

whereas If I read this dataframe via absolute hdfs path location, it seems that it is not able to filter the data using partition key column:

```py
emp_df_2 = spark.read.format("orc").load("hdfs://pathlocation/database/udb.db/temptable/emp_id=6")
emp_df_2.explain(True)

******************************************************************************
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
Relation[emp_name#7411,emp_city#7412,emp_salary#7413] orc

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
emp_name: string, emp_city: string, emp_salary: int
Relation[emp_name#7411,emp_city#7412,emp_salary#7413] orc

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Relation[emp_name#7411,emp_city#7412,emp_salary#7413] orc

== Physical Plan ==
*(1) FileScan orc [emp_name#7411,emp_city#7412,emp_salary#7413] Batched: true, Format: ORC, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[hdfs://pathlocation/data/database/udb.db/tem..., 
PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<emp_name:string,emp_city:string,emp_salary:int>
********************************************************************************
```

Could you please help me to understand the logical and physical plan in both the cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second example partition location is already covered in HDFS path. You can still put parent directory as a path and make use of partitioning with the following code:

```py
full_dataset_df = spark.read.format("orc") \
    .load("hdfs://pathlocation/database/udb.db/temptable")
one_partition_df = full_dataset_df.where(full_dataset_df.emp_id == 6)
```

It's worthy to mention that no matter which of these 3 methods you will use, the data processing performance will be the same.

Comment: I think not, there is nothing wrong with your question. I will upvote it, this is at least what I can do :-)